# forEach not modify java(8) collection

Tags: java, java-8

Say I have an Integer list and I'm using Java 8 forEach method on the list to double its values.
Say I have the following code:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(2,3,6,1,9);
l.forEach(p->p*=2);
```

As forEach method take Consumer and calls it accept methos. 
I print the list after runnig the above code and the original list doesn't change.

As far as I understand Stream doesn't alter the source but here I just call accept method on each element...

Thank u in advace

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason that forEach does not mutate the list comes down to the specification:

The javadoc for [`forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) says:

> `default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)`
>
> ..... The default implementation behaves as if:
>
> ```
>      for (T t : this)
>          action.accept(t);
> ```

As you can see:

- The `action` is a `Consumer`; i.e. it doesn't generate a value.
- The semantics don't allow for the `this` collection to be updated.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. But if T is some object reference and I change its content within forEach loop I should  see its new content.

Comment: No, that's not true with or without lambdas, and never has been.

Comment: @user1409534 - You could change the contents of object that the object reference points to, but that does not update the list.  To update the list (in the way you are attempting to do), you would need to replace the object reference in the list with another one.  You can't do that with a `forEach()`.  And certainly the lambda won't / can't do it.

Answer (score 34):

The method `forEach` only iterates through the elements of the list without changing them, If you want to change the elements, you can use the method `replaceAll`:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(2,3,6,1,9);
l.replaceAll(p->p*2);
```

Answer (score 11):

Try to use `map` insted of `forEach` to alter original `List`.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2,3,6,1,9);
list=list.stream().map(p -> p * 2).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: That creates a new list, it doesn't mutate the existing list. It's probably better that way, but it's still important to be aware of the distinction.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I am aware of using map in order to get new collection and map metod of stream. I don't understand why forEach metod on collection doesn't alter the element if its only calling accept metod of the given lambda?