# Altering string array values in lambda

Tags: arrays, lambda

How would one add values to current values in a String array with lambda?

```
String[] array = {"test1", "test2", "test3"};

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){
    array[i] = array[i] + "stack";
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

output:

```
test1stack
test2stack
test3stack
```

`Arrays.stream(array).foreach()`; how you would manipulate it in the foreach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [forEach not modify java(8) collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852286/foreach-not-modify-java8-collection)

Comment: @Asiriel Do you really want to preserve the modified elements or the output is all you desire?

Comment: @Joe can you please explain how it's a duplicate? This is not a list of integers nor is the question based directly on Java 8 but more on lambda expressions. Using the above works fine, I would like to learn how to do it using Lambda expressions

Comment: @nullpointer the idea is to have values added to all elements in the array and then use Java 8's String.join to convert the array to a comma seperated string.

Comment: *values added to all elements in the array* is what makes it a duplicate of the linked question possibly.